# How can I switch the Month and Day when the column format is M/D/Y?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am not sure if this has already been answered but I could not find anything.

I am trying to convert the column of dates from `MM/DD/YYYY` to `DD/MM/YYYY`.

I must confess that I don't even know where to begin on this. I was thinking I might try an update statement but I am unsure as to how to format it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't change the position of the month and day, fix your data type. Dates should be stored in a date and time datatype not a `varchar`. `03/07/2020` is not **before** `12/01/2010`, but with a `varchar` it ***is***. Changing the format fixes nothing, fix the data type. Worry about the format in the presentation layer.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? `Char(10)`, `Date` or something else?

Comment: The datatype is Nvarchar(255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two level of conversation :

```
select convert(varchar(12), convert(date, datecol, 101), 103)
```

In general, you need to fix the data-type (if that is in your hand) instead of doing conversation in `SQL`. Date formatting should be done at the presentation layer.

Comment: I am trying to migrate the data into a database that I have no control over the data-type. It will only let me move the data into the corresponding column if it is in the DD/MM/YYYY format. The data I was given is in the MM/DD/YYYY format.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by fixing the data type in the actual table. For displaying purpose either on a webpage, reports or whatever.

SQL Server provides a number of options you can use to format a date/time string. In select, you can try one of the suggested methods as [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/).

For all these conversions you need to pass the date values in proper data type which may be the date or date-time.

Here is one of the examples of your illustration.

```
declare @DateInString varchar(20)  = Cast(getdate() as Varchar(20))
select convert(varchar(12), convert(date,  @DateInString, 101), 103)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do `Select Format(datecol, 'dd/MM/yyyy')`

This will return your datetime field as a varchar - you should then be able to insert that into your target.